# MVC 3 Selecting and deselecting checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that displays a few images with checkboxes allowing the user to decide whether to save each image. I'm hiding the checkboxes, and instead using a checkmark or an X on top of the image to represent whether or not it is selected. This is all working fine. However, the value of the checkbox is not changing - it always remains unselected.

Here is my code in the view:

```
<div class="imgCheckBoxes">
    <label for="MyImages_Cover" class="imgCheckBox">
        <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="cover" />
    </label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyImages.Cover, new { @class = "check-box hideChkBx chkForImg" })
</div>
```

Which renders the following HTML:

```
<div class="imgCheckBoxes">
    <label for="MyImages_Cover" class="imgCheckBox">
        <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="cover" />
    </label>
    <input class="check-box hideChkBx chkForImg" id="MyImages_Cover"
        name="MyImages.Cover" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="MyImages.Cover" type="hidden" value="false" />
 </div>
```

My jQuery code is as follows (removed some code dealing with positioning, etc):

```
var closeBtn = '../Content/img/close.png';
var okBtn = '../Content/img/ok.png';

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    if ($('.imgCheckBox').html() != null && $('.imgCheckBox').html() != '') {
        initializeOkCloseImg();
    }
    $('.chkForImg').change(function (e) {
        initializeOkCloseImg();
    });
});

function initializeOkCloseImg() {
    var chkImg = '';
    $('.chkForImg').each(function (index, element) {
        chkImg = closeBtn;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            chkImg = okBtn;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is working correctly in terms of switching the images denoting checked/unchecked, but when the form is posted the checkbox is always false. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured out the problem. The problem was actually not with the jQuery, but with my view model. Apparently this wasn't working because I was using a model inside my view model (MyImages.Cover). This for some reason threw everything out of wack. When I just use a standard bool in my view model, everything works perfectly. I have no idea why that is, but it kind of sucks since I need to reuse this logic on a few pages and defining individual properties in every view model seems tedious and unnecessary. Wish there was an easier way!

Answer (score 0):

In your post method, do you return the Model with the updated values (in this case the checkboxfor's value **MyImages.Cover**).

Comment: In controller action for the form post, the values are saved to a database, and then the user is redirected to the GET action which retrieves the model and returns it to the view. My controller actions and everything are working fine because the other information is being saved and displayed correctly, its the jQuery that seems to be the problem.